# SQL Server: Returning Results of Group By Based on Substring of Column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, cursor, substring, resultset

For more context on this question please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276760/sql-server-group-query-based-on-substring-of-column?noredirect=1#35276760).

I have a query which uses `GROUP BY` with a substring

```
    use thedatabase;

    declare @fromDate datetime = '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000';
    declare @toDate datetime = '2016-02-02 23:59:59.999';
    declare @source varchar(15) = 'server001';

    DECLARE @countForType bigint;
    DECLARE @totalForType decimal(30,8);

    DECLARE @country varchar(10);

    SELECT  @countForType = count(*),
            @totalForType = SUM(typeTable.amount),
            @country = 
                case
                when (charindex('[', typeTable.source) > 0 and charindex(']', typeTable.source) > 0)
                then substring(typeTable.source, charindex('[', typeTable.source) +1, (charindex(']', typeTable.source) - 1) - charindex('[', typeTable.source))
                else null
                end
    FROM 
        theTypeTable typeTable (nolock)
    WHERE 
        typeTable.startDate > @fromDate
        AND typeTable.startDate < @toDate
        AND typeTable.source like @source 
    GROUP BY                     
        case
            when (charindex('[', typeTable.source) > 0 and charindex(']', typeTable.source) > 0)
            then substring(typeTable.source, charindex('[', typeTable.source) +1, (charindex(']', typeTable.source) - 1) - charindex('[', typeTable.source))
            else null
        end
```

I'd like to be able to get this into a report format, either by looping through and print out values with PRINT or place the it all in a result set.  Either would be fine.

From researching, there are two things that I could do here to compile a report:

1. Use a cursor and loop through the results, printing the values. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.
2. Get rid of the scalar variables and have this query return a result set. I've done this below. Below is the re-written query. However, it just returns a single row.

Returns a single row:

```
Select  count(*) as countForType, 
        SUM(typeTable.amount) as totalForType, 
        case
            when (  charindex('[', typeTable.source) > 0 and 
                    charindex(']', typeTable.source) > 0)
            then substring( typeTable.source, 
                            charindex('[', typeTable.source) +1, 
                            (charindex(']', typeTable.source) - 1) - charindex('[', typeTable.source))
            else null
        end
        as country

FROM theTypeTable typeTable (nolock)
WHERE typeTable.startDate > @fromDate
  AND typeTable.startDate < @toDate
  AND typeTable.source like @source 
GROUP BY 
    case
        when (  charindex('[', typeTable.source) > 0 and 
                    charindex(']', typeTable.source) > 0)
            then substring( typeTable.source, 
                            charindex('[', typeTable.source) +1, 
                            (charindex(']', typeTable.source) - 1) - charindex('[', typeTable.source))
            else null
        end
```

Which returns something like:

```
countForType    totalForType    country
=========================================
590             82983909        NULL
```

Ideally, I'd like a report, either in a result set or printing the output, that has the following information:

```
countForType: 104
totalForType: 110000.00000000

country: en-US
countForType: 55
totalForType: 95000.00000000

country: de-CH
countForType: 25
totalForType: 5000.00000000

country: tr-TR
countForType: 30
totalForType: 10000.00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can use a bit scripting, like

```
SELECT  'countForType: ' & count (*) + '
totalForType: ' & SUM(typeTable.amount) as totalForType 
FROM 
....
```

Here after the last apostrophe in the line, I pressed enter, that will make the line change part of the query.

Execute the query in Text mode, by pressing Ctrl+T first and hope you will get the result.